# Running javascript function conditionally - Razor, HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

Right now I have a table that's created dynamically using user selection + data. Sometimes, there are errors with the data, and I'd like to let a user know in the table.

Razor (the link takes you to ~/ControllerName/givenID)

```
<tr id="@givenID">
     <td>@Html.ActionLink(name, someMethod, "ControllerName", new { id = givenID }, new { title = "", id = givenID })</td>

     @if (errorConditions)
     {
     <div id="@givenID" onload="addErrorMessage(this)"  data-test="ErrorMessage" style="display: none"></div>
     }
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
  //adding custom tooltip to document
  $(document).tooltip();

  //adding error message to standard
  function addErrorMessage(element)  {
    var theElemOfID = document.getElementById(element.id);
    theElemOfID.title = element.attr("data-test");
    theElemOfID.style.color = rgb(255, 0, 0);
  } });
```

I'm trying to add a title to the ActionLink (so it can be used by the tooltip) and also change the color of the link, but only when the the errorConditions are true.

Right now when I run, nothing happens. The addErrorMessage never calls, but all the information is in the places I expect (as in the link has the right ID, etc).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do not use `onload`. It is not supported, except for on `<body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onload` is only supported on the `<body>`, but it is **highly** recommended that you **do not use inline event handlers!**

Use an inline script, like this (using jQuery since you seem to be using it):

```
@if (errorConditions)
{
    <div id="@givenID" data-test="ErrorMessage" style="display: none"></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            addErrorMessage($('#@givenID'));
        });
    </script>
}
```